# Подскажите как можно организовать мини-колл центр без стационарного телефона

Tags: база-данных, crm

Мне нужно сделать какое-то подобие call-центра с базой данных, где будут храниться клиенты, их адреса и какие-то еще данные. Чтобы при звонке, если информация о клиенте есть в бд, он бы автоматически определялся, подключались бы какие-то его данные. Все это должно без использования стационарного телефона.
Спасибо заранее за любые ответы по теме.

Comment: Ставите программную АТС, например asterisk и разруливаете через нее звонки куда угодно и заодно в БД данные из логов забираете

Comment: Я взял сейчас на тест Mango Office. Как считаете, этот вариант будет приемлем в использовании?

Comment: я не знаю, что они сейчас предоставляют. если данные о текущем звонке  в онлайне вам в БД отдадут то почему бы и нет

Comment: Заранее извиняюсь за глупый вопрос. Я ведь не смогу подключить к тому же asterisk свой мобильный телефон?

Comment: Вы можете с астериска перебросить звонок на мобильный номер (просто позвонить с ip или стационарного номера). Или принять звонок с мобильного (на ip или стационарный). Или установить на мобильном какую нибудь программу ip-телефонии и через интернет связать ее с астериском